# React and Next map returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I have been working with NextAuth for a few hours and have been using the Twitter API to login/search for tweets

I have got most of the things set up with ease however there's some issues with my client side fetching oof the API routes I created on the server.

Index.js

```
export default function Home() {
const { data: session } = useSession()
  const [statuses, setStatuses] = useState();


 useEffect(() => {
    
 fetch('api/twitter/search')
 .then(response => response.json(),)
 .then(response => setStatuses(response))
 .catch(err => console.error(err));

 console.log(statuses)

  
 }, [])



 
 



  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
      Welcome {session.user.name}<br/>
        Signed in as {session.user.email} <br />
 
      
        {statuses.map((st) => (
         <p>{st.data.id}</p>
))}


        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
    </>
  )
  

  
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      session: await getSession(context),
    },
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

Even tho I have checked in my React dev tools that the `statuses` state indeed has the data I'm trying to map over.

EDIT - console.log of `statuses`

[image: console.log(statuses)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export default function Home() {
const { data: session } = useSession()
  const [statuses, setStatuses] = useState([]);


 useEffect(() => {
    
 fetch('api/twitter/search')
 .then(response => response.json(),)
 .then(response => setStatuses(response?.data))
 .catch(err => console.error(err));

 console.log(statuses)

  
 }, [])


    return (
    <>
      {session && 
        <>
          Welcome {session?.user?.name}<br/>
          Signed in as {session?.user?.email} <br />
          {statuses?.map((st) => (<p>{st?.id}</p>))}
          <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
        </>
       }
      {!session &&
        <>
          Not signed in <br />
          <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
        </>
    </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      session: await getSession(context),
    },
  }
}
```

You are getting `session` value before your `state` is being set inside the `useEffect`. Adding `?` before map would remove the error `statuses?.map`

Comment: I've given this a try and the error is the same, it jus says .map is not a function now.

Comment: Oh the first one is for a signed in user and the second is for signed out, the third one was a typo I just edited my code, thanks

Comment: So I just tested with your code and get this error `TypeError: statuses.map is not a function` and yes I'm sure the api is getting responses, I'm even able to see it in my react dev tools.

Comment: Can you console.log(statuses) like this {console.log(statuses)} before map line and add to your question the result from that console.log ? Maybe your response type is object and you try to map it without reaching to array @KentrellJr

Comment: Just added the console.log picture in the question

Comment: I see the error now. You should set your state like this setStatuses(response?.data) and remove data from p tag {st?.id}. I edited my answer @KentrellJr

Comment: That really did work, thank you so much, I had no idea about this `?.`